# vendor.js:55639 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'create/path1'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

x.componet.ts

`const path="path1"`

x.component.html

```
[routerLink]="['create',path]"
```

`<router-outlet name="modal"></router-outlet>`

modulex-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'create',
    children:[
      {
        path:'path1',component:path1Component,outlet:'modal'
      },
      {
        path:'path2',component:path2Component,outlet:'modal'
      },

    ],
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

app.routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component:HomeComponent,
    outlet:'home'
  },
 ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HomeModule
  ],
  providers: [
    DatePipe
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'create/path1'

in modulex routing created some routes with respective components
and in app-routing using preloadmodule approach , when tries to access  'create/path1' it says

> Error: Cannot match any routes.

am I Missing anything?

**if remove outlet name everything works**

Comment: You should explain the problem not just add the error logs and file names

Comment: @reymon359 New to stack overflow, thanks for guidance .can you help?

Comment: Where do you import `HomeRoutingModule` ? Add any lazy loaded routes that you have

Comment: @david in app.module.ts inside imports

Comment: Show AppModule file. It's likely that you are not importing it correctly

Comment: @David Kindly check post now